# Change Combo Box style

Tags: html, css

I want to change the cmbobox design I rtied to use this code it's working on chrome
but it not working on opera and firefox
HTML code:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>Here is the first option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.styled-select select {
       background: transparent;
       width: 268px;
       padding: 5px;
       font-size: 16px;

       border: 0;
       border-radius: 0;
       height: 34px;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
       appearance: none;
       }

.styled-select {
       width: 271px;
       height: 43px;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: url(img/cmbbox.png) no-repeat;
       border: 0;
       }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sz2e6/

Comment: What *exactly* isn't working? Are you only trying to remove the default arrow?

Comment: Every browser has it default style which can be manipulated with JS/JQuery. Use [UniformJS](http://uniformjs.com/), it works.

Answer (score 1):

Full CSS styling of select elements is only support in Chrome browsers. For details, see the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript).

Since that answer was posted, Firefox has gained some support for styling selects, but not all styling options will be available.

For cross-browser solutions, the normal approach is to hide the select and to style another element to *look* like a select control.