# Selectbox dropdown styling

Tags: html, css, select, area

I am working on a project where i need to style a selectbox.
I can easy style the selectbox to match the psd, but when it comes to the dropdown area, its driving me nuts.

How is that possible? I have tryed with adding a overlay to the dropdown area with som css stuff, but i can't get it to work well.

The code for selectbox:

```
#sidebar select{
        background: transparent;
        width:148px;
        height:31px;
        border:0;
        border-radius:3px;
        line-height:1;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        outline:none;
        color:silver;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
        font-style: italic;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .styled-select{
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url('../images/icons/selectbox.png') no-repeat right; 
        border:0;
    }

<div class="styled-select">
   <select class="selectbox">
   <option value="">Hollaws</option>
   <option value="">Hollaws</option>
   <option value="">Hollaws</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

[A small fiddle for example is provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ542/)

Comment: Styling the dropdown area is not possible without getting nuts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152144/change-combo-box-style

Comment: what do you want to get? show us your psd

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `background-color: transparent;` and `border: 0;` for `select` element, and also make sure your `select` element is larger than the container element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ542/1/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ542/2/) *(Little better looking demo)*

```
.styled-select{
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('http://www.simonsweb.dk/selectbox.png') no-repeat right; 
    border:0;
}

.styled-select select {
    width: 180px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are getting it, maybe i don't explain it proberly though. I need to style the dropdown area, the fiddle you provided does not work :) :/

Comment: @SimonDuun So what I just did there in my fiddle?

Comment: As per your query, Mr. Alien's solution is perfect +1

Comment: @SimonDuun Just in case if you meant to change the dropped down box, than that's not possible with pure CSS only, also, if you think the dropped options are far from the main one, than get rid of the `height` property from `.styled-select select`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your cool suggestions. I actually ended up using a FansySelectBox plugin, that works cross browser.

http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/

Edit: I don't know in this case if it is acceptable to answer my own question in this case or?