# Different Output of my Selectbox On Browsers

Tags: html, css

I have used selectbox with basic style. Though on different browsers like safari and mozilla its looks different.

Here is my CSS:

```
.select { 
padding:7px; 
min-height:30px; 
background:#CCC;
border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
border-radius: 4px;   
font-size: 13px; 
}
```

Here is the html

```
<select class="select">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way show select box unique. I don't want to use custom jquery selectbox

Comment: What looks different? Each browser has its own way of rendering HTML elements. You can't really control that with CSS..

Comment: `<select>` has limited styling ability.

Comment: @putvande I guess OP concern select should have same looks across all browsers.

Comment: @error404, only one solution is use a image on select, that is only a CSS solution.. check this SO link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159894/selectbox-dropdown-styling?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used `min-height` unnecessarily. Remove it and check your code again.

```
.select { 
padding:7px; 
background:#CCC;
border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
border-radius: 4px;   
font-size: 13px; 
}
```

You can increase or decrease the padding as per your required height.

Answer (score 0):

First search result in Google returned:

[Fully custom select box, simple css only](https://coderwall.com/p/w7npmq)

The idea is to wrap the select in an element, then reset as much of the styling as possible. All browsers display `<select>` differently.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/ACGoD)**